# How do I theme the contact form?

Tags: theming, forms, 8

I am trying to create a contact form for users with username, email, message, and submission button, but I want to customize the structure of the form.

Where do I get the structure of the form to customize it?

Contents of ContributeForm.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\contact_form\Form\ContributeForm.
 */

namespace Drupal\contact_form\Form;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\UrlHelper;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ChangedCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CssCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;

/**
 * Contribute form.
 */

class ContributeForm extends FormBase implements FormInterface{


    protected $accepted_domains = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com'];
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'contact_form_contribute_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */

    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        /* $form[ '# attributs'] [ 'class'] [] = 'well white-box';*/
        $form['intro'] = array(
            '#markup' => t('Use this form to send a message to an e-mail address. No spamming!'),
        );
        $form['Full Name'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => '<label class="control-label" for="input01">'.t('Full Name').'</label>',
            '#required' => TRUE,
           /* '#attributes' => array('class' => 'input-xlarge text-tip'),*/
        );
        $form['email'] = array(
            '#type' => 'email',
            '#title' => $this->t('Email address'),
            '#required' => true,
           /* '#prefix' => '<div class="control-label">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>' */

        );

        $form['Type of feedback'] = array(
            '#type' => 'radios',
            '#title' => $this->t('Feedback'),
            '#description' => t('Type of feedback'),
            '#options' => array(
                t('Comments or suggestions'),
                t('Questions'),
                t('Report a problem(s)'),
                t('Other'),
               /* '#prefix' => '<div class="form-horizontal well">',
                '#suffix' => '</div>'*/
            )
        );
        $form['Subject'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Subject'),
            '#required' => true,
           /* '#prefix' => '<div class="form-horizontal well">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>'*/
        );
        $form['Your Message'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textarea',
            '#title' => $this->t('Your Message'),
            '#required' => true,
            /*'#prefix' => '<div class="form-horizontal well">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>'*/
        );

        $form['my_captcha_element'] = array(
            '#type' => 'captcha',
            '#captcha_type' => 'recaptcha/reCAPTCHA',
            '#required' => true,
          /*  '#prefix' => '<div class="control-group">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>'*/
        );
       /* $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';*/
        $form['actions']['sendt'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Send'),
        );
        $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
            '#name' => 'op',
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Cancel'),

        );
        return $form;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */

    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        if (!filter_var($form_state->getValue('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $form_state->setError($form['email'], 'Email address is invalid.');
        }

        if (!$this->validEmailAddress($form_state->getValue('email'))) {
            $form_state->setError($form['email'], 'Sorry, we only accept Gmail or Yahoo email addresses at this time.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
            drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value);
        }
    }

    protected function validEmailAddress($email) {
        $domain = explode('@', $email)[1];
        return in_array($domain, $this->accepted_domains);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 contact forms are completely customizable through the UI. Site builders can use the built-in contact forms or can create new ones. The built-in forms have all the standard fields (Name, Email, Subject and Message) but you can also add any other field you need.

To work with contact forms go to Structure > Contact forms (admin/structure/contact). Here you can select *Manage fields* to add additional fields, *Manage form display* to select which field are visible on the form, and *Manage display* to customise the appearance of individual fields.

Comment: But with the contact form module  I can not add recaptcha in my form

Comment: To add a captcha to a form you can use [Mollom](https://www.drupal.org/project/mollom) or [reCAPTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha). Mollom is stable in d8 and reCAPTCHA is at rc1

Comment: but when I add new field there is no type field (recaptcha), I have already installed the recaptcha module But I created my custom module called (contact_form), I created my form with fields but my problem is that how to access fields in my Twig (How to display the form with Twig)

Answer (score 0):

Form alteration is done with implementing hook_form_alter() in a custom module.

Comment: my problem how to access the different field of my form in the file Twig??

Answer (score -1):

For this problem I think best solution is use module Webform https://www.drupal.org/project/webform, for me this is one of the best Drupal module. Also for this module you have great documentation and demo examples.